# What is the notation used in references called?

Tags: syntax, coding-style, naming-conventions

I'm trying to find out how to read/write notations like this:

```
jQuery.getJSON( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] )
```

or

```
string http_build_query ( mixed $query_data [, string $numeric_prefix [, string $arg_separator [, int $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC1738 ]]] )
```

What are these called? I want to be able to Google it.

Comment: try googling "documentation conventions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are method signatures. They define method name and number, type and order of method parameters. Parameters enclosed in [] are optional.